# Why does 'x' work as a CSS property when styling an SVG?

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to work out just what things I can control on an SVG via CSS.

Here's an example that shows where sometimes attributes can be controlled via CSS and sometimes they can't:

```css
div {
 border: dashed 1px grey; 
 padding: 0.5em; 
}

rect.controlled-by-css {
 stroke: red; 
 stroke-width: 2px; 
 x: 5; 
 y: 20; 
 height: 10px; 
 width: 10px; 
}

line.controlled-by-css {
 
 x1: 25; 
 y1: 25; 
 x2: 40; 
 y2: 40; 
 
 stroke: red; 
 stroke-width: 2px; 
}
```

```html
<div> 

<svg> 
   <rect stroke ="black" x ="0" y ="0" height ="10" width ="10"/> 
   
   <line stroke ="black" x1 ="15" y1 =" 15" x2 ="25" y2 ="0"/> 
   
   <rect class ="controlled-by-css"/> 
   
   <!-- this line won't show up - x1, x2, y1, y2 are invalid property names --> 
   <line class ="controlled-by-css"/> 
</svg> 
</div>
```

What's going on here?

I've looked at this MDN documentation,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/Presentation

where it says:

> SVG presentation attributes are CSS properties that can be used as attributes on SVG elements.

But x, y, are not listed as presentation elements, yet can still be controlled with CSS.

How do I know which attributes can be controlled with CSS, and which can't?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/rect scroll down a little and it will confirm x is a property that can be controlled using CSS. **Note:** Starting with SVG2 x, y, width, height, rx and ry are Geometry Properties, meaning those attributes can also be used as CSS properties for that element.

Comment: @Gerard Yeah -thanks - I saw that as I was writing the question, :}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the documentation for [`<rect>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/rect)

> Note: Starting with SVG2 x, y, width, height, rx and ry are Geometry Properties, meaning those attributes can also be used as CSS properties for that element.

More details about Geometry Properties at the [w3 documentation here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-SVG2-20150915/geometry.html).

It also looks like presentation attributes are also controllable by CSS - as indicated by the [documentation for the transform property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform).

Here is more general documentaiton from w3 about styling:
https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/styling.html

The relevant documentation is:

> **6.6. Presentation attributes**
>
> Some styling properties can be specified not only in style sheets and ‘style’ attributes, but also in presentation attributes. These are attributes whose name matches (or is similar to) a given CSS property and whose value is parsed as a value of that property. Presentation attributes contribute to the author level of the cascade, following all other author-level style sheets, and have specificity 0.
>
> Since presentation attributes are parsed as CSS values, not declarations, an !important declaration within a presentation attribute will cause it to have an invalid value. See Attribute syntax for details on how presentation attributes are parsed.
>
> Not all style properties that can affect SVG rendering have a corresponding presentation attribute. Other attributes (which happen to share the name of a style property) must not be parsed as a presentation attribute and must not affect CSS cascading and inheritance. Also, only elements in the SVG namespace support presentation attributes. Most SVG presentation attributes may be specified on any element in the SVG namespace where there is not a name clash with an existing attribute. However, the geometry properties only have equivalent presentation attributes on designated elements. Attributes of the same name on other elements must not affect CSS cascading and inheritance.
>
> Except as noted in the table for the transform presentation attributes, the presentation attribute name is the same as the property name, in lower-case letters.

Comment: Note though that this part of SVG2 has not been implemented in every browsers yet (e.g FF).